# Using coffescript in rails views doesn't work properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, erb

I'm trying to use coffescript as views in Rails 3.2.11

I have create.js.coffee with the following lines:

```
is_valid = <%=@model.valid?%>

if is_valid
  res = confirm("Are you sure you want to continue?")
  if(res)
    <%=@model.activate%>
    window.location.href = "/blabla/models"
  else 
    return
else
  $('.form .field_with_errors').removeClass('field_with_errors')
  jw_funcs.respond_with_error(<%=@response_invalid%>)
```

The problem is that the line of code  <%=@model.activate%>
is executed every time. I think it depends on the fact that the erb engine runs independently from the coffee engine; If so, how can I do this ?

Comment: Yes ERB and Coffeescript are two different template handler. ERB is not called when you use the .coffee extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really weren't expecting this coffee code to call your model method from the client's browser, were you?

Wrap `@model.activate` into its own controller action, which will be called by clients if the confirmation is given. Something like this:

```
res = confirm("Are you sure you want to continue?")
if(res)
  $.ajax('/models/1234/activate', ...)
else 
  return
```